# Showing results in a new window (leaflet maps) [R Studio]

Tags: r, window, leaflet, rstudio

We are trying to make an automated process where we map out species distribution on a map. This we are succeeding in with this code, however it seems impossible to get these results (the distribution map) in separate windows. Right now it just overwrites the maps during the loop, so we only end up with the last one. The package we are using is robis (from the obis website).

The following is the script we are using:

```
year = 2006
while (year <= 2015) {
  data <- occurrence("Phocoena phocoena", year = year)
  mapp = leafletmap(data)
  show(mapp)
  year = year + 1
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with robis package, but have you tried adding dev.new() in front of the command for plotting the chart?

Answer (score 0):

As you don't give a reproducible example here is some example code using `leaflet`

```
library(leaflet)
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Stamen.TonerLite"))
ind <- c(1:10)
for (i in ind) {
  m <- addCircleMarkers(map = m,
                       lat = 40 + ind[i],
                       lng = 8 + ind[i],
                       color = "blue",
                       stroke = FALSE,
                       radius = 10,
                       fillOpacity = 0.8,
                       clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
}
print(m)
```

I hope that helps. If not, please provide data and the packages you are using.